# Calling APIM in customer Tenant using Access token retrieved from multitenant app

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-active-directory, multi-tenant, azure-api-management

I have a MT-App that authorizes users in my multi tenant application.
When a users logs in I verify that the issuer of the id-token is a known tenant from AzureAd. Using the GUID from the tenant.

Works like a charm :D

Now the a customer want me to do some "writeback" to their source system, by calling an API exposed through APIM.

I thought this is what OIDC/oAuth was all about, but I am not able to find any good examples on how to do this.

First thing I'm struggling with is actually how to get the access token.

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;

services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddAzureAD(o =>
                     {
                         o.OpenIdConnectSchemeName = AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme;
                         o.Instance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/";
                         o.TenantId = "organizations";
                         o.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc"; 
    
    
                 OnTokenValidated = e =>
                 {
                     //This can not be the way to do it. but for now. 
                     var accestoken = e.SecurityToken.RawData; //This is the AccessToken
```

For now I'm storing the access token in a cookie, probably not the best way,
I have seen some docs mentioning a SaveToken option, but does not seem to be part og the AddAzureAD extension options.

After that calling APIM with the access token in the Authorization Header should do the trick?
Or do I need to register some application in apim?

Anyone!

I'm fumbling in the dark :D

Comment: Have you added your multi-tenant application to customer tenants?

Comment: Yes, the authentication part of my application is working.  What I'm struggling with is calling APIM in the customer tenant  in the context of the logged in user.

Comment: Did you get the token? Did you try to call the api?

Comment: Seems that the token that I get this way is an Identity Token not the access token.

Comment: Got the right access_token using the `HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token")`

Comment: Great! I will summarize our discussion in the answer so that it can help more people, you can mark it as an answer. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you Carl. I will try to add some more info here as well when everything is working as expected.. :D

Comment: Is there an update?

Answer (score 0):

> After that calling APIM with the access token in the Authorization
> Header should do the trick? Or do I need to register some application
> in apim?

As you said in the comments, what you get is an identity token instead of an access token. You need to modify the code and use `HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token")` to get the access token.

In addition, you do not need to register the application in apim, because you already have a multi-tenant application, you only need to add it to the customer tenant, and I think you have already done so.

Finally, by the way, don't forget to add [policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies#ValidateJWT).